# Can't find specific table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have been using BeautifulSoup to scrape the pricing information from 
"https://www.huaweicloud.com/pricing.html#/ecs"

I want to extract the table information of that website, but I get nothing.

I am using Windows 10 , the latest BeautifulSoup , Request and Python3.7

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.huaweicloud.com/pricing.html#/ecs'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
soup.find_all('table')
```

After running the `soup.find_all('table')` , it returns an empty list: `[]`

Comment: 1. Most of content on the shared url is loaded using Javascript(xhr requests), so you need to find those xhr requests and get data(or use browser automation like selenium)
2. On the fully loaded page, I can't find any 'table' element from the browser.

Comment: @Kamal Oh, I am sorry for that, when you enter the website , click "产品价格详情" button then you will see the table , If you don't understand Chinese, you may see the button on the line below the top line, where there are three buttons :"产品价格详情"，"价格计算器"，"价格计算清单0: 0.00"，the first one is what I need

Comment: I think what @Kamal is saying is that the data isn't in the html file that you are loading. If you look at the source of the page and find the tag with `id="content"` you'll see that there's only a few placeholder tags in there. All of it gets stuffed into those tags after the page loads with javascript which you won't be able to see the results of by just pulling the source. You should use a method that @Kamal describes.

Comment: As @ZachWoods explained, you cannot find the data with your code, because it is not loaded so simply and you need another way. Once you decide if you want to use only requests(via xhr requets) or use browser(like selenium) then you can find detailed ways to get that data. And you can also ask for help in that method if you face issue.

Comment: Info seems to be at this endpoint,https://portal.huaweicloud.com/api/get-products?bundleFlag=1&regionCode=cn-north-1&status=ONSALE&cloudServiceType=hws.service.type.ec2&resourceType=hws.resource.type.vm&productTagCodes=general.online.portal, but it times out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not the answer to your question, but this might help you. This is the code I came up with using selenium & BeautifulSoup. You just have to specify the location of chromedriver, and the script is good to go.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.huaweicloud.com/pricing.html#/ecs'

driver = webdriver.Chrome("location of chrome driver")
driver.get(str(url))
driver.find_element_by_id("calculator_tab0").click()
time.sleep(3)
html_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, features="lxml")
table_all = soup.findAll("table")

output_rows = []
for table in table_all[:2]:
    for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
        thead = table_row.findAll('th') 
        columns = table_row.findAll('td')
        _thead = []
        for th in thead:
            _thead.append(th.text)
        output_rows.append(_thead)
        _row = []
        for column in columns:
            _row.append(column.text)
        output_rows.append(_row)

output_rows = [x for x in output_rows if x != []]

df = pd.DataFrame(output_rows)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer!! I just come up with using selenium , I didn't expect that BeautifulSoup can work with selenium!.